# An efficient code to determine if a set is a subset of another set

Tags: matlab, set, wolfram-mathematica

I am looking for an efficient way to determine if a set is a subset of another set in Matlab or Mathematica.

Example:
Set A = [1 2 3 4]
Set B = [4 3]
Set C = [3 4 1]
Set D = [4 3 2 1]

The output should be: Set A

Sets B and C belong to set A because A contains all of their elements, therefore, they can be deleted (the order of elements in a set doesn't matter). Set D has the same elements as set A and since set A precedes set D, I would like to simply keep set A and delete set D.

So there are two essential rules:
1. Delete a set if it is a subset of another set
2. Delete a set if its elements are the same as those of a preceding set

My Matlab code is not very efficient at doing this - it mostly consists of nested loops.

Suggestions are very welcome!

Additional explanation: the issue is that with a large number of sets there will be a very large number of pairwise comparisons.

Comment: Do you know anything about the elements of the set? are they only integers? are they only withing a certain range? If so, think about setting up a one dimensional boolean (bit) array, with each element corresponding to an integer being in A. So one pass over A to form this array, then one pass over B to check if each element of B is in A (just see if that flag is true in the array).  If these are integers within a known range then you should get something in the area of O(n) for efficiency.  If they are not integers, or of an unknown range - a hashing scheme could work in a similar manner.

Comment: Yes, they can only be integers. The maximum size of a set is also known.

Comment: Have you actually verified that you have a problem with pairwise comparisons taking too much time?  You can cut the number of comparisons by sorting your sets according to size, since B can only be a subset of A if it is smaller or the same size as A.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the set of sets { [1,2], [3,4] }?  I.e., do you intend to return the empty set ("No set is a superset of all the sets") or do you intend to return {[1,2],[3,4]} ("All sets were subsets of these sets")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will likely want to take a look at the built-in [set operation functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/set-operations.html) in MATLAB. Why reinvent the wheel if you don't have to? ;)

*HINT:* The [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) function may be of particular interest to you.

**EDIT:**

Here's one way you can approach this problem using nested loops, but setting them up to try and reduce the number of potential iterations. First, we can use the suggestion in [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287289/marc)'s comment to sort the list of sets by their number of elements so that they are arranged largest to smallest:

```
setList = {[1 2 3 4],...  %# All your sets, stored in one cell array
           [4 3],...
           [3 4 1],...
           [4 3 2 1]};
nSets = numel(setList);                       %# Get the number of sets
setSizes = cellfun(@numel,setList);           %# Get the size of each set
[temp,sortIndex] = sort(setSizes,'descend');  %# Get the sort index
setList = setList(sortIndex);                 %# Sort the sets
```

Now we can set up our loops to start with the smallest sets at the end of the list and compare them first to the largest sets at the start of the list to increase the odds we will find a superset quickly (i.e. we're banking on larger sets being more likely to contain smaller sets). When a superset is found, we remove the subset from the list and break the inner loop:

```
for outerLoop = nSets:-1:2
  for innerLoop = 1:(outerLoop-1)
    if all(ismember(setList{outerLoop},setList{innerLoop}))
      setList(outerLoop) = [];
      break;
    end
  end
end
```

After running the above code, `setList` will have all sets removed from it that are either subsets or duplicates of other sets preceding them in the list.

In the best case scenario (e.g. the sample data in your question) the inner loop breaks after the first iteration every time, performing only `nSets-1` set comparisons using [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html). In the worst case scenario the inner loop never breaks and it will perform `(nSets-1)*nSets/2` set comparisons.

Comment: Writing a logical test to check if a set is a subset is not the problem really. What I want to avoid is making a very large number of pairwise comparisons between sets. For example, if I keep my sets in a matrix, I would like to apply an operation to the entire matrix to extract rows with correct sets.

Comment: @Edward: I've updated my answer with a complete solution for you to try. Hopefully it is more efficient than what you were trying previously. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the question you mean to ask is "given a list of sets, pick out the set that contains all of the others". There are a bunch of edge cases where I don't know what output you would want (e.g. A = { 1, 2 } and B = { 3, 4 }), so you need to clarify a lot.

However, to answer the question you *did* ask, about set containment, you can use set difference (equivalently complement wrt another set). In Mathematica, this sort of thing:

```
setA = {1, 2, 3, 4};
setB = {4, 3};
setC = {3, 4, 1};
setD = {4, 3, 2, 1};
Complement[setD, setA] == {}
 True
```

indicates setD is a subset of setA.

Comment: I added some clarifications above. The output should be set A because it contains sets B and C and set D is simple a rearranged set A. Also, the problem is not designing a logical test to check if a set is a subset but to avoid having a very large number of pairwise comparisons. Therefore, my question is more about an efficient way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that if no set is a superset of all the supplied sets, you wish to return the empty set.  (I.e. if no set is a superset of all sets, return "no thing".)

So, ..., you want to take the union of all the sets, then find the first set in your list with that many elements.  This isn't too hard, skipping the reformatting of the input into internal list form...  Mathematica:

```
    topSet[a_List] := Module[{pool, biggest, lenBig, i, lenI},  
        pool = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[a]];  
        biggest = {}; lenBig = 0;  
        For[i = 1, i <= Length[a], i++,  
            lenI = Length[a[[i]]];  
            If[lenI > lenBig, lenBig = lenI; biggest = a[[i]]];  
            ];  
        If[lenBig == Length[pool], biggest, {}]  
    ]
```

For instance:

```
    topSet[{{1,2,3,4},{4,3},{3,4,1},{4,3,2,1}}]  
      {1,2,3,4}  
    topSet[{{4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3}, {3, 4, 1}}]  
      {4,3,2,1}  
    topSet[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]  
      {}
```

As a large test:

```
    <<Combinatorica`  
    Timing[Short[topSet[Table[RandomSubset[Range[10^3]], {10^3}]]]]  
      {14.64, {}}
```

I.e., a set of 1000 randomly selected subsets of the range [1,1000] was analyzed in 14.64 seconds (and, unsurprisingly none of them happened to be a superset of all of them).

--  Edit - Escaped a less than that was hiding a few lines of implementation.  Also ...

Run time analysis: Let L be the number of lists, N be the total number of elements in all the lists (including duplicates).  The pool assignment takes O(L) for the flattening, and O(N) for the deletion of duplicates.  In the for loop, all L assignments to lenI cumulatively require O(N) time and all L conditionals require at most O(L) time.  The rest is O(1).  Since L<N, the total run time, O(L)+O(N)+O(N)+O(L)+O(1), is O(N).  I.e., the superset, if it exists, can be found in time proportional to the length of the input -- the sum of the lengths of the individual sets.  And the constant hidden behind the big-O isn't large.

Proof of correctness:  A superset, if it exists, (1) contains itself, (2) contains any permutation of itself, (3) contains every element present in any (other) set, (4) is as long or longer than any other set in the collection.  Consequences: A superset (if present) is the longest set in the collection, any other set of equal length is a permutation of it, and it contains a copy of every element contained in any set.  Therefore, a superset exists if there is a set as large as the union of the collection of sets.

Answer (score 0):

In *Mathematica* I propose using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) for this.

For example, if we have a set `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and we wish to test if set `x` is a subset we could use:  `MatchQ[x, {(1|2|3|4) ..}]`.  The advantage of this construct is that as soon as an element which does not belong is found the test will stop and return False.

We can package this method as follows:

```
maximal[sets_] :=
  Module[{f},
    f[x__] := (f[Union @ Alternatives @ x ..] = Sequence[]; {x});
    f @@@ sets
  ]

maximal @ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 1}, {3, 4, 1}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 1}}
> ```